# How to recover my parachain if my relay chain has an error "Import failed: Unexpected epoch change"

Tags: parachain

I have a parachain connected to my relaychain.

A couple of days ago my relaychain has an error: "Import failed: Unexpected epoch change"

Apparently there is no solution to it than to destroy the database.

If you delete the database of your relaychain, your parachain is also useless.  Why?

How can we save our parachain if for some reason the relaychain collapse?

Answer (score 1):

`Import failed: Unexpected epoch change` That looks like your relay is using BABE and hasn't produced a block for longer than an epoch. Which makes me curious about what version/release of polkadot your relay nodes are running. As I can see this [PR #11727](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/11727) allows skipping over empty epochs (Hopefully I have understood correctly that PR).

When hitting this state there is not much actions you can take, and as you mention usually the outcome is dropping the relay db.

What you are not 100% right about is the parachain part. Keep in mind that the parachain maintains a totally separated db than the one from the relay. Though, in the state of your relay there are some storage values that point to a parachain in one way or another.

With this what I want to say is that you should not be necessary to drop your para db in this scenario. It should be enough to spin up a new relay, run the collators with the correct parameters in case some have changed and do the registration with the proper information on the relaychain. And this is more or less the key point of not needing to drop your para db.

What you want to register is the state at the last head of your parachain as the "inital state" that you are asked for by the registrar pallet in the relay, and for the code, use the wasm running on the para at that moment.

If obtaining this "initial state" from a parachain that has been running for some time is not clear to you, one of the ways one can do this is by using the `export-state` subcommand that the binary provides.

And just to reiterate, the parachain and the relaychain keep totally separate dbs, so even in the case of one of these two getting corrupted, that doesn't affect nothing else than that db.

Comment: Thanks.  This is what we hoped to happen.  The parachain should be separate from the relaychain as seen in the database itself.  Now with regards to making the parachain working again after the failure of the relaychain is the magic solution that I would like to do.

Comment: Can you point me to a documentation as to how to do this please?

Comment: I tried: ./target/release/parachain-template export-state --chain parachain-chainspec.json > parachain-init-state

Comment: Then registetered it to my relaychain as genesisHead file + wasmFile (validationCode).

Comment: I got an error: Could not decode the head data. error=Error

Comment: Read carefully the doc for that command, `Export the state of a given block into a chain spec`. What you are getting as output is a chain spec, then you can use that one to generate the "genesis" state and wasm.

Comment: Thanks so much.   I used the chainspec to run the node up again, then I created a new state, using export-genesis-state, the output file is the same with the original genesis state.  I register it anyway, still cannot find blocks.  Is there a special command or utility to generate the "genesis" state from the new chainspec?

Comment: I got an error: Could not find the header of the genesis block in the database! block_hash=0x922d43a0606e6c6315c301bcbd7c27ba5c8e88f9665e85b621796c82c81ce780

Comment: interesting, check that `paraId` is still matching everywhere

Comment: Should I retain the paraId?  I check the raw chainspec it is 1200, similar to the old one.